# JavaFX Splash sceen with GIF

Tags: javafx, java-8

Recently I have developed a personal software to help me with my daily schedule. I have tried to have a splash screen of Homer Simpson eating, as a cool startup splash screen, But unfortunately the GIF won't play.

here is the whole code

```
public class Homer extends Application
{
    public static final String SPLASH_GIF =
            "https://media.giphy.com/media/JRQ1PegFVKXBu/giphy.gif";
    private static final int SPLASH_WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int SPLASH_HEIGHT = 224;
    private Pane splashLayout;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    { launch(args); }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage initStage) throws Exception {
        ImageView splash = new ImageView(new Image(
                SPLASH_GIF
        ));
        splashLayout = new Pane();
        splashLayout.getChildren().add(splash);

        Scene scene = new Scene(splashLayout, SPLASH_WIDTH, SPLASH_HEIGHT);
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        initStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        initStage.setWidth(SPLASH_WIDTH);
        initStage.setHeight(SPLASH_HEIGHT);
        initStage.setScene(scene);
        initStage.show();
        System.out.println("finished");
    }
}
```

---

Having the picture format to be switched to PNG as following will work

```
public static final String SPLASH_GIF =
        "http://www.dashboardwidgets.com/showcase/data/43/homerQuotes-1p2f.png";
```

It will result in just a simple picture of Homer, not eating a banana. I would like to have it with a GIF.

How can it be possible?

Comment: Please edit the question and add the gif to the question.  If it works with a png, it should also "just work" with a gif.  So it should work as long as JavaFX is understanding your particular gif file format correctly (which it should...).  I wonder if you are doing other work on the JavaFX application thread which is preventing the gif animation from running.  To determine any loading format failure you can add listeners to the image error and exception properties and use System.out debug routines to output their values.

Comment: @jewelsea I have conclude in the original post isolated code example of the problem which still remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying your example, I can put it down to a

```
com.sun.javafx.iio.ImageStorageException: No loader for image data
```

If I use a different URL with an animated gif that is loaded by http and not by http**s** (http://www.picgifs.com/music-graphics/music-graphics/beatles/music-graphics-beatles-186070.gif) and there the ImageView is working.

I also downloaded Homer with the banana and saved it and loaded it with

```
final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image("file:JRQ1PegFVKXBu.gif"));
```

The ImageView works al right with that.

I found no hint in the JavaFX API that https is not supported, but it would be better anyway to not do a download in you startup splashscreen, as this might take to long.

Comment: @jewelsea you should have posted that as an answer as it's the correct one

Comment: Yep, changed comment to answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Failure is because the source link is to an html file not a gif file**

The issue is that the link in some Folk's question is not actually an image (even though the url ends in `.gif`), it is instead a HTML page or a redirect to a HTML page (you can see this by loading the link in a browser).

If you replace the html link:

- https://media.giphy.com/media/JRQ1PegFVKXBu/giphy.gif

with the actual GIF link:

- https://i.giphy.com/JRQ1PegFVKXBu.gif

then the GIF image loading and display works as expected.

**Aside on protocol support for image loading**

Actually the issue isn't https related. The JavaFX API does implement loading images via https correctly. According to the Image javadoc:

> All URLs supported by [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream--) can be passed to the constructor.  If the passed string is not a valid URL, but a path instead, the Image is searched on the classpath in that case.

The underlying JavaFX image implementation just [opens a stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream--) from the URL class (which can be determined by searching the JavaFX source code).  So any protocol supported by the underlying JRE implementation will work with the JavaFX image class.  This includes `http:`, `https:`, `file:` and `jar:` protocols; and may include others depending upon the JRE implementation.  You can even add [custom protocol handlers](http://media.techtarget.com/tss/static/articles/content/dm_protocolHandlers/java_protocol.pdf) if you wish.